# How can I embed java code into batch script?Is it possible to create .java/.bat hybrid?

Tags: java, batch-file

While there are some techniques that allows you to create the [perfect](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543&start=15) (and not so [perfect](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5260))  batch file hybrids with some 'native' windows script languages.

What a 'perfect' hybrid should look like:

1. The embedded code must be usable as it is and you should be capable
   to copy-pasted it in any other editor/IDE you want. There should be
   no endless echoes to temp files and weird escape sequences.(rather
   possible for every language that support multi-line comments).
2. No 'poisonous' prints of error messages (e.g. **/*** will print an error
   in command prompt despite the execution of the batch will continue
   on the next line)
3. No temporary files.With the exception of compiled binary files which
   is unavoidable for the languages that does not have an interpreter.

Is it possible to create the 'perfect' java/batch hybrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is almost.

The main impediment is that the all compilers I know are very strict about the file extensions and will refuse to compile any file that has no `.java` extension.

As any command in batch files starting with `@` will be not displayed we can use the java annotations to silence the error message that comes from the java comment (should be saved with `.bat` extension):

```
@Deprecated /* >nul 2>&1

:: self compiled java/.bat hybrid
::
:: deprecated is the only one annotation that can be used outside the class definition
:: and is needed for 'mute' start of multi-line java comment
:: that will be not printed by the batch file.
:: though it still creates two files - the .class and the .java
:: it still allows you to embed both batch and java code into one file

@echo off
setlocal
java -version >nul 2>&1 || (
    echo java not found
    exit /b 1
)

::find class name
::can be different than the script name
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=} " %%c in (`type %~f0 ^|find /i "public class"^|findstr /v "for /f"`) do (
    set "javaFile=%%c"
    goto :skip
)
:skip

copy "%~f0" "%javaFile%.java" >nul 2>&1

javac "%javaFile%.java" 
java "%javaFile%"

::optional
::del %javaFile%.* >nul 2>&1 
end local
exit /b 0

*******/



public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       System.out.println("selfcompiled .bat/.java hybrid");
    }
}
```

The example above covers points 1. and 2. but of course there's still need of creation of .java file.Still copying is faster than echoing java content line by line.

**One step further** (or half step) - making a `.java` extension to act like `.bat` (or almost)

Lets say you don't the like the part in the code that finds the java class name and the self-copy code.
You can make the .java extension to act like .bat file.Or almost - the `%0` will be lost and the file name will be stored in `%1`.
For that purpose you need to call this batch file with admin permissions:

```
   @echo off
   :: requires Admin permissions
   :: allows a files with .JAVA (in this case ) extension to act like .bat/.cmd files.
   :: Will create a 'caller.bat' asociated with the extension
   :: which will create a temp .bat file on each call (you can consider this as cheating)
   :: and will call it.
   :: Have on mind that the %0 argument will be lost.


    rem :: "installing" a caller.
    if not exist "c:\javaCaller.bat" (
       echo @echo off
       echo copy "%%~nx1"  "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat" /Y ^>nul
       echo "%%temp%%\%%~nx1.bat"  %%*
    ) > c:\javaCaller.bat

    rem :: associating file extension
    assoc .java=javafile
    ftype javafile=c:\javaCaller "%%1" %%*
```

Then the self-compiled .java file will look like this (should be saved with `.java` extension):

```
@Deprecated /* >nul 2>&1


:: requires ran javaExtInstaller.bat
:: https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/Java/javaExtInstaller.bat
:: 
:: self compiled java/.bat hybrid
::
:: deprecated is the only one annotation that can be used outside the class definition
:: and is needed for 'mute' start of multi-line java comment
:: that will be not printed by the batch file.
:: allows you to embed both batch and java code into one file

@echo off

setlocal
java -version >nul 2>&1 || (
    echo java not found
    exit /b 1
)


if not exist "%~n1.class" javac "%~nx1" 

:: to compile the class every time use:
:: javac "%~nx1" 

java "%~n1"


endlocal
exit /b 0

*******/



public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       System.out.println("selfcompiled .bat/.java hybrid");
    }
}
```

there still will have a creation of temp `.bat` file by the  `javaCaller.bat` but it will be not 'visible' and batch part is much shorter.

In the examples there are no packages as the only single java file is used .Packages will make only the example harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you saw [my DosTips post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6185) on Alternate Data Streams? This method have all the advantages you want for perfect hybrid scripts because the non-Batch code is stored *in its own space* (alternate stream), so it don't requires a single additional character! The code can be edited with Windows Notepad. The "only" problem is if the java compiler was designed to recognize the Alternate Data Stream. I successully tested this method with VBS, JScript and PowerShell, but unfortunately I have not a java compiler installed...

However, the test to check if this method work with your java compiler is very simple. Copy the code below and create BatchJavaTest.bat file with it:

```
@echo off

rem Compile the java code stored in this file as an ADS with name "TestClass.java"
javac "%~F0:TestClass.java"
java "TestClass"
```

Now we need to create the ADS with the java code. To do that, enter the following in the command-line:

```
notepad BatchJavaTest.bat:TestClass.java
```

When Notepad open, paste the following on it:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       System.out.println("selfcompiled .bat/.java hybrid from an ADS!");
    }
}
```

Save this file and test the Batch one. That is it!

Please, report the result!

PS - This program must be tested in a NTFS disk in order for it to work...

Comment: unfortunately compiler reports an error:`comp.bat:TestClass1.java:1: error: class TestClass1 is public, should be declared in a file named TestClass1.java`  seems to be very strict about file names.Anyway plus one.

Comment: the second compiler I've tried was the eclipse compiler - mainly java classes.It was unable to read the content from ADS... The next is OpenJDK  (and probably the last)

Comment: May I suggest something? Try to find any reference on management of ADS's _as data files_ in the compiler documentation. Powershell indicate that version 3 manages ADS, but after read the docs I realized that this was implemented in just a few commandlets. This point was the key that allowed me to run a .ps1 file stored in an ADS... Perhaps is there a compiler switch?

Comment: But even if the compiler is not capable of directly compile an ADS, it is much simpler to extract the java code from the ADS instead of anyone of the other methods: `more < "%~F0:TestClass.java" > TestClass.java` **&** `javac TestClass.java`