# How to execute java file from the batch file code?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

```
@echo off
cd\
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;
cd "C:\Users\Atiq\workspace\Biometric2\src\smack\comm\sample\"
java OfficeFrame8.java
exit
```

I am new to java language. Could you please guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: The `java` executable file only executes a compiled java file, so you will need to first compile your java file using the command `javac OfficeFrame8.java` and then run it using `java OfficeFrame8`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi [This is no longer true since Java 11](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/).

Comment: Does `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" "C:\Users\Atiq\workspace\Biometric2\src\smack\comm\sample\OfficeFrame8.java"` work (assuming it's a [single-file program](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/))? Otherwise and since you tagged your question with _eclipse_, in the run configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that.

Comment: you might take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190126/how-can-i-embed-java-code-into-batch-scriptis-it-possible-to-create-java-bat